# tracking actual changes in rows when updating table

Tags: mysql, algorithm, audit-logging

I have a table which i keep on updating, from the values of other source in my code. The value I update may or may not be same as the value already in the row.

I need some kind of algorithm may be via mysql (db) or otherwise (part of code) so that I later may be able to identify which rows have a changed value.

There is a date modified column which I change.  But that will not be a true indicator as it will always be updated. I want a way by which I can determine whether some predefined columns have changed values,

One solution is this:  I can do a select query, then compare and update a changed flag in the table. But that seems complex and not for me as I have a table with a lot of records

Another solution might be to save the md5 checksum of the values in a column and while updating compare the previous md5 and current md5 and so on.

I want to know the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fairly simple way to handle this problem. Let's think of it as managing when a row's timestamp gets updated.

First of all, as I'm sure you know, your table needs a timestamp column with default settings for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. That looks like this if the column is called `ts`.

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Second, you can use an UPDATE query like this to change the values in a row.

```
UPDATE stock
   SET val1 = 'newval1', 
       val2 = 'newval2', 
       changed_by = 'current_user_id'
 WHERE id = 'id_to_change'
   AND NOT (val1 == 'newval1' AND val2 == 'newval2')
```

The `AND NOT` clause on the `WHERE` will prevent the update from taking place unless `'newval1'` or `'newval2'` would actually provide new values. This works because no rows match the `WHERE` clause in the update.

When the update is prevented from taking place your automatically set `ts` column will not change. Neither will the `changed_by` column be set to the present user's `user_id`.  So, you have the time and user of the most recent genuine change.

Also, many host language interfaces to MySQL have a method call to determine how many rows were affected by a recent `UPDATE` operation. With this technique, you'll get back zero rows when the row is not updated. That might be convenient for your user interface.

Also, this technique uses a single query, so it's safe if more than one user is trying to update the same row at the same time. There's no need to use a transaction to guarantee that.

(Note that tracking the `changed_by` user is optional, and will only work if your application can provide the current user's actual id.)

This is reasonably efficient as long as the database search for `WHERE id = 'id_to_change'` works quickly.

It does require reworking your application's UPDATE queries. But so would any other approach to this problem.